# inject multiple (array) dependencies - ng

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-injector

In angularJs i want to be able to provide multiple strategies for implementing some logic.

Example, I need to calculate interest, and there are multiple implementations (High, NoTax, None)

is there a way to inject an array of services which implement this strategy? allowing the service I inject them into to be able to select the correct strategy (or use them how it sees fit).

side note:
In .NET I would make an interface which the tax stratiges implement, then I could inject an `IEumerable<ITaxStrategy>` into my service. Which JS cannot support.

Comment: Return an array from a factory if you want to inject an array.Angular injector isnt an IoC container,it's at best doing service location.If you want to add strategies at configuration time,use the provide method,and instanciate strategies there

Comment: fun one on top, I need this to be modular, so when a new module is added to the sln, the service will be automatically added to the list.

i guess that the in the factory method it would need to have the injetor and access the list of registered services ( but i do not know how to do that )